# How to make use of the "pinch" touch effect in the Sencha Touch framework?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, web-applications, extjs, sencha-touch

I'm trying to figure out how to make use of the "pinch" touch effect with Sencha Touch. Do you know of any examples that help with the first steps?

The documentation seems to be rather silent about it.

Specifically I'm looking for a common task as a starter:

I want to zoom it - and - zoom out of an image in JPEG format. Do you know if the "pinch" method allows that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i havent seen an example for that yet.

but the Kitchensink example shows how to catch these events. Click the source button.
http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/kitchensink/

you can look at the sourcecode of the pinch gesture to find out what info you get with the event object.
http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/docs/source/Pinch.html

maybe the deltaScale value is what you need